# Receiving undefined references to various Windows libraries when compiling with SDL 2 and -static?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on a modification of the Wolfenstein 3D engine in SDL2 (using Wolf4SDL as a base) and I've run into a problem - when using -static in the linker options, I get a large variety of undefined references to various things. Here's my build log to show what I mean:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Lazarus (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SDL2\lib -o Lazarus.exe .objs\alu_cache.o .objs\alu_dbg_mem.o .objs\alu_gfx.o .objs\alu_hud.o .objs\alu_in.o .objs\alu_me_core.o .objs\alu_me_gui.o .objs\alu_me_symbols.o .objs\alu_me_textinput.o .objs\alu_me_tools.o .objs\alu_me_windows.o .objs\alu_menu.o .objs\alu_pak.o .objs\alu_particles.o .objs\asmcomp.o .objs\id_us_1.o .objs\vieasm.o .objs\wl_act1.o .objs\wl_act2.o .objs\wl_agent.o .objs\wl_debug.o .objs\wl_dir3dspr.o .objs\wl_draw.o .objs\wl_floorceiling.o .objs\wl_game.o .objs\wl_inter.o .objs\wl_main.o .objs\wl_play.o .objs\wl_state.o .objs\wl_text.o  -static -pg -lgmon  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -mwindows 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:52: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_TicksInit': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:106: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:52: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:52: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_GetTicks_REAL': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:159: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_TicksInit': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:106: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:52: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_GetTicks_REAL': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:159: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_TicksInit': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:106: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `timeSetPeriod': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:52: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.o): In function `WIN_CoInitialize': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:68: undefined reference to `_imp__CoInitializeEx@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.o): In function `WIN_CoUninitialize': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:87: undefined reference to `_imp__CoUninitialize@0' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_SetupAPI': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:596: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:609: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:612: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:530: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:545: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:549: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:550: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UILess_GetCandidateList': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:966: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:662: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:666: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:670: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:671: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Disable': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:344: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:668: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:662: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:666: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:670: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:671: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:668: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UIElementSink_BeginUIElement@12': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1033: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UIElementSink_UpdateUIElement@8': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1060: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Init': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:289: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:303: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:304: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UILess_SetupSinks': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1174: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:530: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:545: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:549: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetReadingString': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:402: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:477: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:550: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Quit': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:358: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Enable': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:329: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8' 
C:\SDL2\lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition': 
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:662: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4' 
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 
50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

This does not happen when linking a normal Wolf4SDL mod (which uses SDL 1.2), and it links correctly if I don't use -static but then won't run without various other DLLs being present (namely libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and the like). While I can just change PATH to include my MinGW directory, when it comes time to distribute it I can't expect everyone to have MinGW installed, and I want to keep the number of DLLs I'm distributing with my mod to a minimum considering I'm already using SDL_mixer and SDL_image which come with a ton of DLLs already. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Use an installation program (like InnoSetup) and package all of your components that way.  `I can't expect everyone to have MinGW installed`  Right, and that is the job of an installation program  -- you package all that's necessary to run your application, and let the installation program handle this.  Also, I'm sure the set of redistributable files that are necessary are documented somewhere

Comment: While I could do that, I'd prefer to not have to make people install it; I'd rather it be portable and have all of the necessary DLLs with it. Additionally, this doesn't happen with any other Wolf4SDL mod, nor as far as I can tell with other SDL2 applications. So either I've screwed something up or mingw-w64 is doing something odd, and either way I'd like to figure out what's gone wrong.

Comment: Well, your errors contain `_imp__xxxx` not being found.  That means you are using import libraries, thus DLL's will be used when the application is finally built.  It certainly doesn't look like a build that links to static libraries.

Comment: People don't need all the MinGW distribution to run your application, you just need to ship your executable with shared libraries that your binary need. Like gcc shared library and pthread for a simple SDL2 project.

Comment: I know this, it only needs three specific DLLs to run - libstdc++, libgcc and libwinpthread. The problem is that I'd never had to distribute them with anything before as I'd been able to link statically when using SDL 1.2 without any issues, and I'd rather not have to distribute any further DLLs than I already am.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, fixed the problem - I needed to link a variety of Windows libraries, namely Ole32, Oleaut32, Imm32, Winmm and Version. Not sure why this wasn't the case for SDL 1; it wasn't mentioned in the Migration Guide either so I'm not sure where the difference comes from.

Comment: also don't forget setupapi and gdi32 ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant "use pkg-config --static" since I had compiled a static only version and wanted to use that.

Guess that's just how pkg-config rolls.
Another option (like the OP mentioned) is to either add the libraries you need "out of band" or to modify sdl2.pc so it includes "all the libraries you need" on the Libs: line (not Libs.static: line which probably already has them).

Again, that's how pkg-config rolls :|