# SDL2 undefined reference to several functions with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl

I have the following project directory structure:

```
/program1
  /bin
  /include
    /SDL2
  /lib
  /resources
  /source
    makefile
```

I read a lot Q&A here about this problem. But I really don't understand what's going on. I followed all the steps in the articles. I'm using Windows 7 64 bits and I got the include and lib files from `i686-w64-mingw32` paste. I put those files in my directories as I mentioned above.

My simple **main.cpp** code in `source` directory is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] ) {
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) != 0 ) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError( ) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Quit( );
    return 0;
}
```

At the `source` directory I have a **makefile** too, that I'm using with MSYS, and this is the compile command that the makefile is yielding:

```
g++ -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I../include -I../include/SDL2 main.cpp -o ../bin/main.o
g++ ../bin/main.o -L../lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -o ../bin/program1.exe
```

After these two commands, I have this big error :(

```
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.o): In function `WIN_CoInitialize':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:73: undefined reference to `_imp__CoInitializeEx@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.o): In function `WIN_CoUninitialize':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:92: undefined reference to `_imp__CoUninitialize@0'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_SetupAPI':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:617: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:630: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:633: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:551: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:566: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:570: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:571: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UILess_GetCandidateList':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:984: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Disable':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:364: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UIElementSink_BeginUIElement@12':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1051: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UIElementSink_UpdateUIElement@8':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1078: undefined reference to `_imp__SysFreeString@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Init':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:309: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:323: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:324: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `UILess_SetupSinks':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1192: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:551: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:566: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:570: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetReadingString':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:423: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:498: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetId':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:571: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Quit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:378: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Enable':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:349: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_Disable':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:364: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `WIN_SetTextInputRect':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:202: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:209: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionWindow@8'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:210: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:852: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetCompositionString':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:699: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:704: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:890: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:885: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetCandidateList':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:767: undefined reference to `ImmGetCandidateListW@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetCompositionString':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:699: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:704: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.o): In function `IME_GetCandidateList':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:771: undefined reference to `ImmGetCandidateListW@16'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_xaudio2.o): In function `XAudio2Create':
/usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/include/xaudio2.h:1273: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
/usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/include/xaudio2.h:1273: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
/usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/include/xaudio2.h:1273: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
/usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/include/xaudio2.h:1273: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_dinputhaptic.o): In function `SDL_DINPUT_HapticInit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/haptic/windows/SDL_dinputhaptic.c:98: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_SetSystemTimerResolution':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:57: undefined reference to `_imp__timeBeginPeriod@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:51: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_TicksInit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:102: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_SetSystemTimerResolution':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:51: undefined reference to `_imp__timeEndPeriod@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_GetTicks_REAL':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:141: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.o): In function `SDL_TicksInit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:102: undefined reference to `_imp__timeGetTime@0'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `WINMM_CloseDevice':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:170: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutUnprepareHeader@12'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:170: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutUnprepareHeader@12'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:182: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInClose@4'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:187: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutClose@4'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `WINMM_PlayDevice':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:131: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutWrite@12'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `SetMMerror':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:106: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `WINMM_OpenDevice':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:285: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutOpen@24'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:331: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutPrepareHeader@12'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `PrepWaveFormat':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:216: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutOpen@24'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:214: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInOpen@24'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `WINMM_OpenDevice':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:281: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInOpen@24'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `DetectWaveInDevs':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:57: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetNumDevs@0'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:57: undefined reference to `_imp__waveInGetDevCapsW@12'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.o): In function `DetectWaveOutDevs':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:56: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetNumDevs@0'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:56: undefined reference to `_imp__waveOutGetDevCapsW@12'
../lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_dinputjoystick.o): In function `SDL_DINPUT_JoystickInit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/joystick/windows/SDL_dinputjoystick.c:317: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateInstance@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program1.exe] Error 1
```

I already tried to switch my include to "SDL2/SDL.h" and tried to put the include and lib files inside mingw folder and the same error is produced. Is my compilation command wrong?

**EDIT**: The strange thing is: if I modify my compilation command to an absolute path as an example F:/APIs/SDL2/include and lib, the program compiles. Why?

Comment: Linker used static library `libSDL2.a`. For static linking you need to specify all dependencies yourself (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110217/linker-errors-from-sdl2-in-my-project/39128297#39128297). So question narrows down to why it didn't prefer dynamic library. Is `libSDL2.dll.a` there? Are you sure your abs path and `../lib` are the same directory?

Comment: HEY! I'm ashamed of myself... my compilation flags was to dynamic link. I just put the `libSDL2.dll.a` and removed the `libSDL2.a` from my lib directory and everything worked. My absolute path was another directory that there was the `libSDL2.dll.a` so that my program compiled. If you want to make an answer with that I'll give you the "this answer helped me". What a shame. Thanks in advance...

Comment: But I tried to find any "official information" about dynamic and static link and I don't found...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260245/receiving-undefined-references-to-various-windows-libraries-when-compiling-with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linker used `libSDL2.a`, which is static library. Static library lacks dependenciy information so all additional dependencies have to be specified manually. To use dynamic library, you need `libSDL2.dll.a` in your libs paths (newer gcc/mingw should accept `SDL2.dll` as well, even without `.dll.a`, although I never used that). Also of course with dynamic linking you'll need `SDL2.dll` either bundled with your resulting `.exe` or in system directory to actually launch resulting program.

You could put both of these libraries into the same directory, like it is in SDL2 distribution. By default, linker should prefer dynamic library if it can find one, or it could be controlled manually with `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` switches (if you want that, read documentation first - these flags affect all libraries specified after it).

(it only covers mingw; msvc have different library format, and SDL2 have separate download file for it)

Comment: "By default, linker should prefer dynamic library if it can find one, or it could be controlled manually with -Wl,-Bstatic and -Wl,-Bdynamic switches" this additional information helped me a lot for complete understading. I guess I'll read more about it later. Thanks again!